# spacy 3 - lemma_ returned will be empty string

Tags: python, spacy

I normalize ten thousands of docs using spacy 3.

1. To speed up the process, I try this way,

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
docs = nlp.tokenizer.pipe(doc_list)
return [[word.lemma_ for word in doc if word.is_punct == False and word.is_stop == False] for doc, _ in doc_list]
```

but all `lemma_` returned would be empty string.

2. So I directly use nlp(doc) like the following, but it's too slow.

```
a = [[word.lemma_ for word in nlp(doc) if word.is_punct == False and word.is_stop == False] for doc in doc_list]
```

How can I do this properly?

Comment: There is an official speed FAQ. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8402

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in how you are creating the docs.

1. In the first example you use `nlp.tokenizer.pipe()` - this will only run the tokenizer on all your docs but not the lemmatizer. So, all you get is your docs split into tokens but the `lemma_` attribute is not set.
2. In the second example you use `nlp(doc)` this will run all the default components (which are `['tok2vec', 'tagger', 'parser', 'ner', 'attribute_ruler', 'lemmatizer']`. Since the `lemmatizer` is part of the pipeline the `lemma_` attribute is set. But, it slower because you are running all the components, even the ones you don't need.

What you should be doing:

```
import spacy

# Exclude components not required when loading the spaCy model.
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", exclude=["tok2vec", "parser", "ner", "attrbute_ruler"]) 

# Extract lemmas as required.
a = [[word.lemma_ for word in nlp(doc) if word.is_punct == False and word.is_stop == False] for doc in doc_list]
```

Comment: As a note: for `en_core_web_sm` in spacy v3.0 or v3.1, you need to include the following components for lemmatization to work: `tok2vec`, `tagger`, `attribute_ruler`, `lemmatizer`. See details here: https://spacy.io/models#design-cnn